# Join an image and a plot in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I have to do a project in MATLAB that should isolate a lung image and put a contour.

I already have the image isolated and the contour on a plot.

Now I want to join both, but I can't do it. Someone can help me?

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`hold on`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html), see also [these examples](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/01/01/superimposing-line-plots/).

```
I = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
figure;
imshow(I);
hold on;
x = 1:600;
plot(x, x, 'r');
```

This will result in a red line plotted on top of the image.